# CSS display property not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, show-hide

I have a div. Initially, a number is displayed over that div. When I hover the div, the number hides and a paragraph shows. When I hover out, the paragraph hides and the numbers displays again.

I have tried to achieve this with css (display: none and display: block) and jquery (show() and hide()). Both work, but not always. Sometimes, both the number and the paragraph disappear and I have to refresh the page to have them back. It works better on Chrome than other browsers, but even in Chrome it doesn't always work.

The page is online [here](http://bumerangue.pt/sketches.html) so you can try it yourself.

And the code looks like this:

```
div h2 {
   display: block;
}

div:hover h2 {
   display: none;
}

div p {
    display: none;
}

div:hover p {
    display: block;
}
```

Anyone knows how I can fix this?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Try defining z-index for the .temp*, h2 and p. I don't see any other reason why it should not work. It works for me both in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Still doesn't work @RadekPech. In some browsers it just completely disappears most of the times...

Answer (score 0):

Simple program:

```
<div id="testDiv">
    <p class="num">1</p>
    <p class="para" class="invisible">Lorem Ipsum</p>
</div>

<style>
  .invisible {
    display: none;
  }
</style>

<script>
 $(function() {
    $('#testDiv').on('mouseover', function() {
      if($(this).find(".para").hasClass("invisible")) {
          $(this).find(".para").removeClass("invisible");
          $(this).find(".num").addClass("invisible");
      }
      else {
          $(this).find(".para").addClass("invisible");
          $(this).find(".num").removeClass("invisible");
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: JS is not good here because it may fail to execute, CSS solution is way better.

Comment: ^ Why would it fail to execute? o.O

Comment: "... it may fail to execute at the time you think it should." Because browser is not required to execute JS code at specific time and may postpone it which may result in unexpected results.

Comment: If you read the jQuery documentation ( http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/ ) you will find that mouseover event is not very good at precisely tell what the user is doing. And anyway, your code does not do what is expected to do. If you look on the actual Gonçalo's page, there is already JS code better than yours (see main.js line 120).

Comment: This is just a simple explanation to get what he wants. @RadekPech